# Cascading REVOKE not working in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, security

I've read about an SQL option of cascading permissions when issuing a REVOKE statement. I've googled for how this option is implemented in MySQL, but haven't found it at all.

This is the [docs page about the REVOKE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html) and there is no sign of cascading option.

The SQL standard cascade syntax has the following format:

```
REVOKE [GRANT OPTION FOR] privileges ON object FROM user {RESTRICT | CASCADE}
```

Is it possible to cascade permissions revoking in MySQL?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Please provide the URL for that quote.

Comment: I am on 10.1.38-MariaDB. database management systems, 3ed, Johannes Gehrke and Raghu Ramakrishnan, page 699. Syntax naturally differs a little from dbms to dbms.. I put it up just for reference and to better explain what I am searching.

Answer (score 0):

Neither MySQL, nor Mariadb (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/revoke/), has implemented `RESTRICT` or `CASCADE`.

In general, a `REVOKE` can negate only an identical `GRANT`.  You cannot, for example, `GRANT ALL ...`, then `REVOKE UPDATE ...`.

That is, the GRANT/REVOKE feature of MySQL and MariaDB is quite limited.

"Roles" are available in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.0.  (But I don't think that is relevant to your question.)

> Syntax naturally differs a little from dbms to dbms.

Change "a little" to "sometimes a lot".

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't implement the `RESTRICT`/`CASCADE` options in the `REVOKE` statement. Moreover, MySQL implicitly executes `REVOKE` statement in a way which is incompatible with both `RESTRICT` and `CASCADE`.

Let's assume that:

- the root user executed: `GRANT INSERT ON table1 TO user1 WITH GRANT OPTION`,
- then, user1 executed: `GRANT INSERT ON table1 TO user2`,
- finally, the root user executed: `REVOKE INSERT ON table1 FROM user1`.

Now, user2 is still able to add rows to table1.

This isn't the `RESTRICT` behavior - because root user was able to perform `REVOKE INSERT ON table1 FROM user1`.
This also isn't the `CASCADE` behavior - because user2 can still add rows to table1. MySQL removes a privilege for a given user, ignoring whether this user granted this privilege to other users.

The `REVOKE` statement works in the same way for roles granted with the `WITH ADMIN OPTION`.

Unfortunately I haven't found it documented, so the above conclusions are based on tests.

Answer (score 0):

In other databases, `CASCADE` is generally required when revoking a privilege that has been granted `WITH GRANT OPTION`. This is because the user who received that privilege may have granted it to someone else. In that case, we want to revoke the privilege from the user itself, but also from all the other users that received the privilege from her - in a *cascading* way.

MySQL is not able to do such a thing, because it doesn't record the **grantor** of each privilege. You have a `SELECT` privilege on all tables? Fine, but MySQL won't remember who gave you that privilege.

Also, MySQL treats `WITH GRANT OPTION` as a regular permission. This leads to some non-intuitive situations:

1. I give you `SELECT` privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION`;
2. I give you `UPDATE` privilege;
3. I revoke `SELECT` privilege from you;
4. Now you have `UPDATE` privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

I'm sure that people who come from proprietary databases will find this funny, or tragic, but it is what it is.

Unfortunately MariaDB is identical to MySQL in this respect.